# How can I get URL from Node.js to React.js?

Tags: reactjs

Currently, I'm trying to fetch data from node.js to react.js.
And I'm using useEffect to get the data from node.js but for some reason, I can not get the URL from node js. I'm really new to node.js with react.js
So I want to know what is a proper way to fetch the data.
This is my code:

## Server

```js
const app = express();

var client_id =
  "???????????????????????????????????????";
var client_secret =
  "???????????????????????????????????????";
var state_val = "RANDOM_STATE";
var redirectURI = "http://localhost:5000/callback";


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  let api_url =
    "https://www.?????.co.kr/oauth2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" +
    client_id +
    "&redirect_uri=" +
    redirectURI +
    "&state=" +
    state_val;
  res.send("<a href='" + api_url + "'>로그인</a>");
});
```

## Client

```js
  const [d, setd] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/")
      .then(res => {
        return res.send();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        setd(data);
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(d);
```

And when I access this, I got an error like this:
[image]

but when I change the fetch Url like "http://localhost:5000/callback" then it doesn't get the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a cross origin `fetch` request and so your server needs to respond with the correct `Access-Control-*` headers. In this case you need `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

You can use the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package.

```js
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express();

var client_id =
  "???????????????????????????????????????";
var client_secret =
  "???????????????????????????????????????";
var state_val = "RANDOM_STATE";
var redirectURI = "http://localhost:5000/callback";

app.use(cors())

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  let api_url =
    "https://www.?????.co.kr/oauth2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" +
    client_id +
    "&redirect_uri=" +
    redirectURI +
    "&state=" +
    state_val;
  res.send("<a href='" + api_url + "'>로그인</a>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have set everything right, it seems related to the CORS problem. try adding the below middleware to your code:

```
// Add headers before the routes are defined
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // this is related to websites you want to allow them to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

    // you can limit the API methods accordingly
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // choose the headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');


    // Pass to next level
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just curious to know is there any specific reason why you are running node js and react js in separate ports.

Comment: Try to ask your question in a new post, but it is due to the fact that we need two-port to access the frontend and backend at the same time. It is impossible to have a same port for both because we need to have access to them seperately